# Linking a form to a button

Tags: infopath, filter, form

I have created a form in InfoPath that is stored on a SharePoint site.
I have added cascading filters that filter the projects by using a SharePoint list as a data connection.
What I want to do is make it so that a button pops up when a project is selected, and once you click that button, it takes you to a form with the project information. How do I make the button open the project specific form? There are about 500 projects that will have their own forms with their respective project information.
[image]